# When does 秋分后遇壬/逢壬 refer to?

Tags: time

I'm working on the, topolectical, word 出沾.

《四川方言词语续考》explains it as:

> 秋分後遇壬叫入霑，十日滿叫出霑。

李實's《蜀語》defines it as;

> 秋分後逢壬謂之入霑，十日滿謂之出霑○霑謂雨多也。逢壬十日內謂之霑天。諺云： ‘入霑有雨 出霑晴。’

Which is pretty much the same.

The part I don't get is the whole 遇壬/逢壬 part.

壬 could be talking about 壬年, but in the same manner it could also refer to 壬日 and I suppose 壬月 as well.

When exactly is 秋分后遇壬 or 秋分后逢壬?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to [壬日](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/324851187.html).

So `秋分后遇壬` means after `秋分`, from the 1st `壬日` `霑` starts (i.e. `入霑`), after 10 days `霑` ends (i.e. `出霑`). In other words, the period of `霑` is 10 days lasting from the 1st `壬日` after `秋分` to the next `壬日`, which is called `霑天`.

For example, the `入霑` of this year (2017) is [10/2(壬戌日)](http://www.wannianli.net/2017/2017-10-2.html).

---

BTW: In traditional calendar, [干支地支](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B9%B2%E6%94%AF%E7%BA%AA%E6%97%A5/1457609?fr=aladdin) is also used for days, from `甲子` to `癸亥`, circulate with the cycle of 60 days.

Comment: So: 入霑 next year is 2018/09/27, 霑天 lasts from 2018/09/27 to 2018/10/06, and 出霑 is 2018/10/07. Right?

Comment: @user3306356 Yes.